# Conditional type to get number index from property if not undefined ("no matching index signature")

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
type Numbers = [3,65,2,7,3,99,23,555];

interface Options {
  options?: Numbers;
}

type FilterOption = Options['options'] extends undefined ? undefined : Options['options'][number];
```

I want to create a type that references the indexes of "options", resulting in a union. But because the `options?` property is optional (by the question mark), I can't just assign the value: `Options['options'][number]` since it may be undefined.

I created a conditional type to check if it's undefined - but this still would cause the error when trying to get the [number] index:

```
Type 'Numbers | undefined' has no matching index signature for type 'number'
```

I thought it might have to do with "distributivity", so I also tried to disable distribution by adding brackets:

```
type FilterOption = [Options['options']] extends [undefined] ? undefined : Options['options'][number];
```

That wasn't it... so is it a limitation with the "narrowing"? Is there a solution?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAOQK4FsBGMBOBnOBeOAbQGYAaANgFZSAmUgdlLIE5nazLOBdAblFACWAOzBYAZgEMAxvADyUMAID2Q3AG9QcOEoXLVAfgBciVBhx8QAX37ho8AGICANqMzzFK-HHd7shAOQ6Hqr%20XHAwAB6iQgAmuEixMGLCMDFw%20nAJMUkpacY%20Kn6BuoWhhEKmWLxAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to build your own [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), I'd suggest using [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to filter out `undefined` from `Options['options']` before indexing into it with `number`:

```
type FilterOption = NonNullable<Options['options']>[number];
// type FilterOption = 3 | 65 | 2 | 7 | 99 | 23 | 555
```

Your version didn't work because `Options['options'] extends undefined` is simply false.  It didn't help to try to disable [distributivity](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) because your type wasn't distributive in the first place; that only happens if the checked type (before the `extends`) is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type paramter, but `Options['options']` is not.  Indeed you'd have gotten closer with that approach if you turned distributivity *on*, but even that wouldn't have fixed it.  Debugging your way to the solution would have looked like:

```
// original version
type FO0 = Options['options'] extends undefined ? undefined :
  Options['options'][number]; // error

// turn on distributivity by introducing a type parameter
type _FO1<T> =
  T extends undefined ? undefined : T[number]; // still error,
// just because T isn't undefined doesn't mean it has a numeric key

// check for a numeric key instead of undefined, switching true/false branches
type _FO2<T> =
  T extends { [k: number]: any } ? T[number] : undefined; // no error
type FO2 = _FO2<Options['options']>
// type FO2 = 3 | 65 | 2 | 7 | 99 | 23 | 555 | undefined 
// wait, undefined?

// don't add undefined in if the input is undefined.
// don't add anything at all in that case (i.e., never)
type _FO3<T> =
  T extends { [k: number]: any } ? T[number] : never; // no error
type FO3 = _FO3<Options['options']>
// type FO3 = 3 | 65 | 2 | 7 | 99 | 23 | 555
// hooray!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAOQK4FsBGMBOBnOBeOAbQGYAaOANgFZyAmcgdnLLgE5W6WruBdAblCgAlgDswWAGYBDAMbwA8lDBCA9iNwBvUHDgqlq9QH4AXIlQYcAkAF9B4aPABiQgDbjMi5WvyI1yFy5SaC4wADyeBtiEAOR6XurRPAB8hCLmWPygAPRZcJCwcM5uWBHeBMRwAD6UVFVwtHUMdex1tBXV3FR2+U7yAAw+peoxcZGJcDAAHuIiACa4SHMwEqIws3CGcIuzy6vrxtpwQ1Gx+mrYianpmPxwOROYmCqY3Q5wAPqO8gCMoQAqSXwhz+E2mMDmCyWKxEaw2Wyhezgpj+V3QGT4d1y2GUAQeT0wpFeBU+8lo-0BeGBoJm8zgGiIAGtTGk0TdTFIRBA4NY4SiWRYeEj4TtoWsMfcRCo8c9QD1CqSfCSyccRmcEslsrk5V8GuU6tRWo1mqxWu04J06ttdjD1pq4AB3KRCMDkK2i2aGInwEnEclAkA6EFTGmaRnM648dmc7m81ECoUwgBuWHFuUl0pe9gKXwqBB94TVJ1G50SSTt2vkubgZoN1Qa1Sa1RadbNnTtAAsVM8pBAAIR2OxAA)